# ASP.NET 5: Nested model properties not validating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I have added the following filter to return bad requests upon model validation errors:

```
public class ValidateModelFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

I have a two-layered model, i.e.:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    [Required] // This works!
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required] // This works!
    public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
}

public class AddressModel
{
    [Required] // This DOESN'T work :(
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [Required] // This DOESN'T work :(
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

The problem here is that only the properties of `PersonModel` are being validated.

**Why would `AddressModel` properties not be validated?**

Note:  This is for WebApi!

Comment: look here http://forums.asp.net/t/1737269.aspx?Validation+on+nested+classes+and+collections

Comment: @Backs: Didn't Web Api 2.2 provide support for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because the implementation is not checking nested properties if a parent model is null. This makes sense, because there is nothing to validate!

Below will result in a validation error stating that the address property is missing

```
{
    "name" : "name",
}
```

Response for above:

```
{
  "Address": [
    "Field Address is required."
  ]
}
```

Seems correct isn't it?

To get the address validated you need to provide it as an empty object or full object with corresponding properties nulled or empty:

```
{
     "name" : "name",
     "address" : {
     }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "Address.Street": [
    "Field Street is required."
  ],
  "Address.City": [
    "Field City is required."
  ]
}
```

If you don't want to force your client to send the object if it doesn't have any values for it, create flattened viewmodel.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I’ve managed to recreate your issue but in my case, it worked just fine.

The only difference is that I haven’t created the custom `FilterAttribute` like you did.

In short, I’ve created a new MVC 6 application using VS 2015. I’ve chosen the **Web Application** in the ASP.NET 5 Preview Template and kept the **Individual User Accounts** as the Authentication.

By doing so, this allowed me to have an up-and-running sample without having to add all the `jquery` files and whatnot.

I then looked at how the `Register.cshtml` view was done for inspiration.

I’ve managed to successfully create two models `PersonModel` and `AddressModel` and added the same properties you did.

I then created a new `Controller` and two `IActionResult`. One for rendering the view (strongly typed) and another for when posting the `<form>`.

The end result is that the client validation works perfectly fine with nested `ViewModels` as long as your fields inside your view respects the naming convention and...of course, as long as you have the appropriate `validate.js` and `validate.unobtrusive.js` files in there.

No need for that custom `FilterAttribute`.

Here is my View:

```
<form asp-controller="NewController" asp-action="Index" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address.Street" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Address.Street" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Address.Street" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Notice the `Address.Street` naming convention for the fields which respects the nested `ViewModels`.

Also notice the `@section Scripts` which renders a partial and the partial has the following:

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Comment: What about server side validation? He hasn't mentioned client side validation and he wants to use ModelState.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am actually using WebApi as well.  No client side.

Comment: You’re right. I didn’t see the last note where you mention this is about WebAPI…my bad.